# Angular: better form validation solution

Tags: angularjs, validation

Need advice about form validation.

I have control structure like so:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <control-wrap>
        <label isRequired="myForm.field1">Some text here</label>
        <custom-control name="field1" 
                  ng-required="true"
                  ng-something-else="any"
                  ng-model="modelForm.field1"></custom-control>
        <info>Some data after control</info>
        <error-list field="myForm.field1"></error-list>
    </control-wrap>

    <control-wrap>
        <label isRequired="myForm.field2">Some text here</label>
        <custom-control name="field2" 
                  ng-required="true"
                  ng-something-else="any"
                  ng-model="modelForm.field2"></custom-control>
        <info>Some data after control</info>
        <error-list field="myForm.field2"></error-list>
    </control-wrap>

    <control-wrap>
        <label isRequired="myForm.field3">Some text here</label>
        <custom-control name="field3" 
                  ng-required="true"
                  ng-something-else="any"
                  ng-model="modelForm.field3"></custom-control>
        <info>Some data after control</info>
        <error-list field="myForm.field3"></error-list>
    </control-wrap>
</form>
```

And this is completely AWFUL, unDRY and I guess I'm doing something very wrong.

I want to stop using field names, but I don't know how to pass ngModel to the sibling the proper way (now I'm forced to pass ngModel via attributes to isRequired and error-list).

Best solution for me ofc is to **require:** '^ngModel' from isRequired and error-list.

Any advice will be very appreciated.

**P.S.** there is no way for me to store fields in json object, there is a lot of logic between fields and different tweaks on labels and hints.

Comment: Maybe you need smth like: invent one directive for all your controls, fiill the form by ng-repeat of that directive, than in its template perform all necessary logic with validation?!

Comment: P.S. in a question states, that I can't use ng-repeat. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I came to this solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/mPXpEaZs2uWZb3WRkmgp?p=preview

Maybe it's not the best solution, but I don't need names anymore.

The main idea is to set model reference to parent container and watch this reference from other children.

So in the end I have:

```
    <control-wrap>
        <label link-required>Field1 label:</label>
        <input link-to-wrap ng-model="mc.field1" 
            type="text" 
            ng-required="true" 
            ng-minlength="5" 
            ng-maxlength="10" />
        <errors-list></errors-list>
    </control-wrap>
```

**UPDATE**

Some more thoughts about storing validation rules with model:

https://plnkr.co/edit/6ZVv685oSRDt7ELBKb9z?p=preview

New directive `my-rules` and extended data in `controller.js`

Comment: I like this; if you also want model validation, i.e. define the validation constraints in the code and not in the view - additionally being able to invoke validation programmatically, you may want to take a look at [egkyron](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron).

Comment: Thx @NikosParaskevopoulos , but my case just in anti-use cases. :) My forms is way too simple for a 3rd party library. In my example I just show a way to bind fields to validation errors spots. In real solution, I guess you should store some validation rules in JSON indeed, with related messages, maybe some i18n service.

Comment: Updated Plunker based on your comment :)

Comment: Looks it is well suited for the "simple forms" case! A comment by looking at the code: `myRules` could require the `ngModel` and add `$validators` for each case. This way your setup becomes more extensible - you can add new validators just by implementing the validation function, not a directive. Then again, this is minor for what you want (and you would have to re-implement Angular's standard validators).

Comment: I also suggest you accept your answer, this way people will know the status of this question in the future (and may be more helpful).