# What's the best way to reduce repetition of form element attributes in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm designing an AngularJS 1.5.x app that will have lots of forms and lots of fields per form. I'm finding that I'm repeating attributes a lot, e.g.:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="thing.Field1">Field 1</label>
    <input class="form-control ctrl-md"
           type="text"
           id="thing.Field1"
           name="Field1"
           ng-model="thing.Field1"
           ng-maxlength="30"
           required
           uib-tooltip="Field 1 is required"
           tooltip-placement="right"
           tooltip-trigger="none"
           tooltip-is-open="thingForm1.Field1.$invalid && showValidationErr('Thing1')"
           ng-blur="fieldBlur('Thing1')">    
</div>
```

I've attempted to use a directive + template, and it works more or less, but it seems very complex and slow.

Is there a good way to make the `input` reusable? Or should I just get used to doing a lot of copy+paste in my editor?

In addition to reducing repetitive coding, it would be nice to be able to change all elements in one place, in the case that I want to change the tooltip position on all fields for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways. Have a look at this library http://angular-formly.com/. In my projects I use plain inputs and writing directives only in a complex cases, like 2 field controls. Or special field like card expiration date.

**UPDATE**

Ok, have a look at this pls. [Angular: better form validation solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769241/angular-better-form-validation-solution)

You have 3 solutions:

1. To store your attributes as it is.
2. To store a group of attributes, commonly used together, in a directive. Or use directive which utilize array of properties. Like validation directive in my example.
3. To use directive with transclusion to utilize 1st and 2nd approach. So you can swap elements position (such as label, input control, error hint) in a single place. Plus you can easily create property like... `preset` on this directive and store attribute presets in it.

So, as I already told, there is many ways to reduce number of attribute repetition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked at Formly and I'd prefer to do this 1) without adding a dependency and 2) without moving design elements from HTML to JS. Also, in addition to reducing repetitive coding, it would be nice to be able to change all elements in one place, in the case that I want to change the tooltip position for example. (I'll update the question to add this.)

Comment: Thanks @Kindzoku. I accepted the answer but can't upvote. :( After playing with some of the options you mentioned, I've decided to stick with copypasta (actually editor snippets and auto code gen). The directive approach feels too brittle and slow.

Comment: Well, the question was about DRY code without copy-paste :)

Comment: Indeed, hence the accept (and upvote, which SO says was "recorded"). Many thanks!